# Formulario de registro carga datos en local, pero al subirlo a godaddy da error en tabla

Tags: php, servidor, registro

Estoy armando una web, y en la parte de registro tengo un formulario que en local me carga los datos, pero al subirlo al servidor de GoDaddy me da error en tabla. Puedan ayudarme, gracias

```php
<?php
                    
if(isset($_POST["botonEnviarEstudiante"])){

$nombreEstudiante=$_POST['nombreEstudiante'];
$apellidoEstudiante=$_POST['apellidoEstudiante'];
$institucionEstudiante=$_POST['institucionEstudiante'];
$cursoOtallerEstudiante=$_POST['cursoOtallerEstudiante'];
$cedulaEstudiante=$_POST['cedulaEstudiante'];
$emailEstudiante=$_POST['emailEstudiante'];
$celularEstudiante=$_POST['celularEstudiante'];
$contrasenaEstudiante=$_POST['contrasenaEstudiante'];
$rolEstudiante= $_POST['rolEstudiante'];
                    

            
$sqlusuarios="INSERT INTO usuarios (nombre, apellido, ci, email, clave_de_Acceso, celular, rol)VALUES ('$nombreEstudiante','$apellidoEstudiante', '$cedulaEstudiante', '$emailEstudiante', '$contrasenaEstudiante', '$celularEstudiante', '$rolEstudiante')";
            
$sqlestudiante="INSERT INTO estudiante (ci, institucion, nombre_Curso) VALUES ('$cedulaEstudiante','$institucionEstudiante', '$cursoOtallerEstudiante')";
                
if(!$conexion->query($sqlusuarios)){
    echo "Error en el registro de informacion";
    exit;
}else{
    /*echo "<script>alert('Ok registro de usuario guardado')</script>";*/               
                
    if(!$conexion->query($sqlestudiante)){
        echo "Error en el registro de informacion de estudiante";
        exit;
    }else{
        echo "<script>alert('Tu registro se ha guardado exitosamente! Comunícate con Arroba Visual para que se apruebe tu registro.')</script>";            
        $conexion->close();
    }
}
            
}
?>    

<div id="formEstudiante" class="formEstudiante">
    <form method="post" action="<?php echo $_SERVER['PHP_SELF']?>" name="form_Estudiante" enctype="" accept="">
        <table>
            <h4 class="tituleteForm">Formulario de registro para Estudiantes</h4><br>
            <tr>                               
                <td><label>Rol:</label></td>
                <td><input type="text" name="rolEstudiante" placeholder="aspirante (ASPIRANTE)" value="estudiante (ASPIRANTE)" readonly><br> <br></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td> <label>Nombre: * </label> </td>
                <td><input type="text" name="nombreEstudiante" size="" maxlength="20" required> <br> <br> </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td> <label>Apellido: *  </label> </td>
                <td> <input type="text" name="apellidoEstudiante"  size="" maxlength="20" required> <br> <br> </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td> <label>Institución: </label> </td>
                <td> <input type="text" name="institucionEstudiante" size=""> <br> <br> </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td> <label>Nombre de <br>curso o taller: * </label> </td>
                <td> <input type="text" name="cursoOtallerEstudiante" size=""> <br> <br> </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td> <label>Cédula: *</label> </td>
                <td><input type="number" placeholder="CI sin puntos ni guiones" name="cedulaEstudiante" maxlength="8" required> <br> <br> </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td> <label>E-mail: </label> </td>
                <td> <input type="email" name="emailEstudiante"> <br> <br> </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td> <label>Celular: * </label> </td>
                <td>
                    </label><input type="tel" name="celularEstudiante" maxlength="9" required> <br> <br> </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td> <label>Clave de acceso: * </label> </td>
                <td> <input type="password" name="contrasenaEstudiante" size="7" required> <br> <br> </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td> <label>Reitera clave<br> de acceso: * </label> </td>
                <td> <input type="password" name="reitContrasenaEst" size="7" required> <br> <br> </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td class="botonEnviar" colspan="2"> 
                <input type="submit" class="botonesOpEd" name="botonEnviarEstudiante" value="Enviar" /> </td>
            </tr>
        </table> 
    </form>
</div>
```

Comment: Dame cinco minutos que saco mi bola de adivino y te digo qué pasa......... Nop, no me funciona la bola hoy. Podrías indicar qué error te da y enseñarnos el código donde está dicho error? También te recomiendo leer [ask] y hacer el [tour] para entender cómo elaborar una pregunta correcta y cómo funciona StackOverflow. Un saludo :)

Comment: Ya agregué el código, gracias, espero comentarios el error da en la tabla usuarios cuando se llena el formulario

Comment: intenta revisar que los campos que estes mandando sean igual a los de la base de datos, son casesensitive y una mayuscula puede considerarla como un campo diferente

Comment: y cual es el error que te da???

Comment: Tu script es vulnerable a ataques SQL y propenso a errores si alguno de los valores incluye comillas o apóstrofes. Te recomiendo usar consultas preparadas para minimizar riesgos.